# How do I make `frame` take up all the space in `canvas`

Tags: python, tkinter

### Code:

```
file1 = 'choose_any_image'


import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = tk.Tk()

def on_frame_resized:
   canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox('all'))

canvas = tk.Canvas(win)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

scroll = tk.Scrollbar(win, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
scroll.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)
canvas.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window = frame, anchor = 'nw')

win.bind('<Configure>', on_frame_resized)

img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file1))

label1 = tk.Label(frame, image = img1)
label1.pack(side = 'top')

win.mainloop()
```

### Output:

Once you've ran the code, you'll see that there's a space between `frame` and `scroll`, which are the frame and scrollbar respectively (shown in the code).

[image: output2]

The white background is the **image** (on the **left**), the **`canvas`** background is on the **middle** (where I have my cursor) and the **scrollbar** is on the **right** (dark grey bar).

### Goal:

[image: output2]

Sorry for the bad quality but I think you get the idea. I just want to **get rid of the spacing**. As you may see, `frame` is attached to `scroll` because `frame` occupies the whole `canvas`.

### What I've tried:

I changed `scroll` master.

```
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient = 'vertical', command = canvas.yview)
```

Unfortunately, `frame` is attached to `scroll` as expected, but doesn't get rid of the unneeded space.

### Explanation:

`canvas` uses up all the space in `win`. Unlike `canvas`, `frame` doesn't. Thus, you're left with a space. How can I get rid of the space? Is the image not big enough? **How do I make `frame` take up all space in `canvas`?** That is, making `frame` take up all the space in `win` as well.

### Concluding remarks:

How do I know the unneeded space comes from `canvas`?

Change `canvas` background color to any color like this:

```
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scroll.set, bg = 'red')
```

Comment: What the point of making the frame the same size of the canvas if you want a vertically scrollable frame?  It makes sense if you only want the frame to expand horizontally.

Comment: Do you want the image to fill the whole frame?

Comment: The whole canvas.

Comment: @acw1668 No, what I meant was: there's a space between the frame, which is in the canvas, and the scroller. If I used up all the space in canvas, the frame will be attached to the scroller. Thus, leaving no space. Note that If the image is big enough, you'll be able to use the scroller, otherwise, not. I fine with that, that's the point of the scroller.